# Kernel Panic - Not Syncing. Segfault at Init

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault, debian, system-administration

I recently tried to install php5-gd package on my debian vmware server and it failed at libc6 - i386.

Afterwards every command other than CD caused a Segmentation fault and the server would no long boot, showing the following error

```
[     4.808086] init[1]: segfault at 0 ip    (null) sp bff4645c error 14 in init[8048000+8000]
[     4.808372] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
[     4.808442] Pid: 1, comm: init Not tainted 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 Debian 3.2.65-1
[     4.808512] Call Trace:
```

<sup>(Trace continued in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9naJ.png)
)</sup>

I am at a complete loss on what to do at this moment. Any help or direction would be appreciated

Edit: I've since uploaded debian-live-8.3.0-i386-standard to the vmware store and booted the broken vm with the live cd.

Now I am in the live cd terminal but not sure what to do next. I did a lsblk and noted that the broken vm's boot partition is sda > sda2 and that's all I have done so far. Do I need to mount this somewhere now?

Edit2: I've now mounted the broken partition into the live cd, however when I tried to chroot, I get Segmentation Fault:

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/tcs1/boot
# mount /dev/tcs1/root /mnt/tcs1
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/tcs1/boot
# mount -t proc none /mnt/tcs1/proc
# mount -o bind /dev /mnt/tcs1/dev
# mount -o bind /run /mnt/tcs1/run
# mount -o bind /sys /mnt/tcs1/sys
# chroot /mnt/tcs1 /bin/bash
# Segmentation fault
```

Comment: cannot chroot into filesystem :/

Comment: Maybe you should rebuild libc and substitute it (via booting with live cd) on your main system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

I relinked ld-linux.so.2 to /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so from a rescue CD and managed to chroot in

Comment: Thanks this help me to save my systems!!! I just wanna add that in archlinux the route is /lib/ld-linux.so.2